# How would you use henderson equation to calculate the pH of a solution containing multiple different acids, such as carbonic acid and acetic acid?

Tags: acid-base

I would like to know if it is possible to use the Henderson equation to calculate the pH of a solution containing more than one kind of weak acid.

Answer (score 2):

In short, as it is, it cannot be used even for a single acid.

The [Henderson-Hasselbalch equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation) (HHE) is nothing else but a little rearranged equation for an acid dissociation constant in the logarithmic form.

$$K_\mathrm{a}=\frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]} \implies \mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log{\frac{[\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]}} $$

HHE is useful if the concentrations of the acid and its conjugate base (anion) are given or easily calculated, like in pH buffers, what is not our case. pH calculations are usually done without prior explicit calculation of the above concentration for HHE.

---

The general scenario of acid-base systems is described by set of nonlinear equations of multiple variables.

For two acids, it involves:

- the equations for dissociation constants
  $K_\mathrm{a,\ce{X}}=\frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{X-}]}{[\ce{HX}]}$
  $K_\mathrm{a,\ce{Y}}=\frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{Y-}]}{[\ce{HY}]}$
  $K_\mathrm{w}=[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]$
- the (molar) amount balances
  $c_0(\ce{HX}) =[\ce{X-}] + [\ce{HX}]$
  $c_0(\ce{HY}) =[\ce{Y-}] + [\ce{HY}]$
- the charge balance
  $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{OH-}] + [\ce{X-}] + [\ce{Y-}]$

So we have 6 equations for 6 variables ( $[\ce{H+}]$, $[\ce{OH-}]$,$[\ce{HX}]$,$[\ce{X-}]$,$[\ce{HY}]$,$[\ce{Y-}]$ ).

The equation set can be easily modified to adapt to different number of acids, with some of them possibly being different dissociation degrees of multiprotic acids, like $\ce{H3PO4}$.

For bases like $\ce{NH3}$, we can use either
$K_\mathrm{a,\ce{NH4+}}=\frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{NH3}]}{[\ce{NH4+}]}$
either
$K_\mathrm{b,\ce{NH3}}=\frac{[\ce{NH4+}][\ce{OH-}]}{[\ce{NH3}]}$

where $K_\mathrm{a,\ce{NH4+}} \cdot K_\mathrm{b,\ce{NH3}}=K_\mathrm{w}$

Solving this equation set usually leads to cubic ( or higher order) algebraic equation for $[\ce{H+}]$, where the exact solution is not convenient to use, or does not even exist. Fortunately, the process of solving can be often simplified by using assumptions of various strong inequalities ( like $[\ce{H+}] \gg [\ce{OH-}]$ or $[\ce{HX}] \gg [\ce{X-}]$). It leads to a much simpler, often quadratic solvable equation. For the resulting pH, the assumed simplifying conditions must be checked for validity, otherwise the approximation has to be rejected.

For convenient solving of the equation set, it is advised to formally replace [] variables by the single-letter symbols,
like $x$,$y$,$z$,$t$,$u$,$v$ for variables
and $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ for given parameters.

In simple or simplified enough scenarios, one may consider in some cases just 1 acid, if acidity of both acids is very different. But even then, formulas to directly calculate the approximated pH value are derived from the original equation for acid dissociation constant.

Comment: Thanks, and if there was also a basic compound in the solution it would still be something along these lines , just adding further complexity. What might that precisely look like ?

Comment: See the updated answer.